# checkcolumn control id in the javascript from the grid panel

Tags: checkbox, store, onload, gridpanel

i need to find the checkcolumn control id in the javascript from the grid panel after datas loaded to store, at the time of loading i need to check the id of the check column if it matches checkbox value should be true, else false. how to do this in EXT.Net grid panel and on which event please suggest me some solution.

Thanks.